# Firebase - LimitToLast - Display Results

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a project for class using Firebase as a database. The project includes a page that pulls info from database to display the movie posters of the last 4 movies you watched.

With my current code I can get console log to display the last 4 urls assigned to each move, but only the most recent one displays in all four poster locations on my site.

The goals is for each poster of the last 4 movies to display in each ID location. I've attached images to help visualize what I mean.

If anyone could point out how to fix this I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
var lastFourRef = firebase.database().ref("events");
lastFourRef.orderByChild("events").limitToLast(4).on("child_added", 
function(snapshot) {
  var lastMovie = snapshot.val().movie;
  var lastHost = snapshot.val().host;
  var lastDate = snapshot.val().date;
  var lastPoster = snapshot.val().poster;

  document.getElementById('img-num1').src = lastPoster;
  document.getElementById('img-num2').src = lastPoster;
  document.getElementById('img-num3').src = lastPoster;
  document.getElementById('img-num4').src = lastPoster;

  console.log(lastMovie);
  console.log(lastHost);
  console.log(lastDate);
  console.log(lastPoster);
});
```

[image: Movie Poster Page]
[image: Console Logs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `child_added`, the function gets called everytime an event is added to that node and the `snapshot` object contains data from that node.

You can use a `counter` variable to display each image in it's `img` element:

```
var lastFourRef = firebase.database().ref("events");
var counter = 1;
lastFourRef.orderByChild("events").limitToLast(4).on("child_added", 
function(snapshot) {
  var lastMovie = snapshot.val().movie;
  var lastHost = snapshot.val().host;
  var lastDate = snapshot.val().date;
  var lastPoster = snapshot.val().poster;

  document.getElementById('img-num'+counter).src = lastPoster;

  console.log(lastMovie);
  console.log(lastHost);
  console.log(lastDate);
  console.log(lastPoster);
  counter++;
});
```

Comment: Absolutely fixed my problem. Thanks so much.